# Is there a way to create a class instance passing to the constructor a list of attributes?

Tags: python, list, constructor, shortcut

Let's say I have this class

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
         self.c = c
```

Is there a way to make a shortcut in the constructor arguments so I don't need to explicitly pass every parameter from a list, for example:

```
def main():
    attributes = [1,2,3]
    foo = Foo(attributes) #instead of Foo(attributes[0], ...., ....)
```

Comment: `Foo(*attributes)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use iterable-unpacking to pass your `list` of arguments as sequential positional arguments:

```
def main():
    attributes = [1,2,3]
    foo = Foo(*attributes)
```

The `*` in front of `attributes` in the call means:

1. `attributes` is an iterable
2. It should be unpacked such that the first element becomes the first positional argument (after the implied `self`), the second element the second positional argument, etc.
3. You're making an assertion that the number of elements you can pull from `attributes` matches the argument count expected by `Foo` (since `Foo` takes three arguments beyond `self`, `attributes` must produce *exactly* three arguments, no more, no less)